# Is there a term for overlapping images due to incomplete film transport?

Tags: terminology, technique, 35mm, double-exposure

When using cameras with manual film transport, it is possible to create partially overlapping exposures, for example by manipulating the transport with the rewind button. Is there a special term for the result or the technique—apart from being a variation of double/multi exposures?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The term people usually use is ["double exposure"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_exposure). As far as I know, it is only useful to do when you don't move film at all, not move it a fraction of a frame length. On many film cameras there is a [special button](http://mir.com.my/rb/photography/hardwares/classics/nikonfeseries/fe/basic4.htm), that will wind the shutter, but prevent film movement (link is to the manual info on Nikon FE).

Not directly relevant to the question, but similar process can be performed on digital cameras (I only used Nikon D3 and [D600](http://www.amateurphotographer.co.uk/technique/camera_skills/master-your-nikon-multiple-exposures-63771)).

Comment: On old manual film bodies that lack such a lever, one can do a double exposure by holding the button on the bottom of the body in, holding the film rewind lever in place, and cocking the film advance. The button on the bottom will disengage the film advance connection and holding the film rewind lever insures that the film doesn't move a little when cocking the lever. (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AjqerXnDAuI)

Comment: @Corey yes, i remember those!

Comment: I still use 'em. I really enjoy the odd looks that I get when I'm changing film rolls :-D

Comment: @Corey While that was true for the majority of 35mm  film cameras, it's still dependent upon the design of each specific camera model. Not all 35mm film cameras behaved that way.